# Dimensions of vector spaces of $n×n$ symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

My book asks for the dimensions of the vector spaces for the following two cases:

1)vector space of all upper triangular $n × n$ matrices, and

2)vector space of all symmetric $n × n$ matrices

The answer for both is $n(n+1)/2$ and this is easy enough to verify with arbitrary instances but what is the formal way to conclude this in the general case, as per the question?

Thanks!

EDIT: I understand how bases and dimensions and linear independe relate. I'm asking how to find the number of dimensions for those two cases above WITHOUT just counting examples where n is equal to, say, 4, 5, 6...

Comment: How many elements can be different from zero in the first row? And in the second? ... Add them to get an upper bound for the dimension. Isn't it  $n(n+1)/2?$ Can you find $n(n+1)/2$ linearly independent matrices? I bet you can.

Comment: I don't understand the question. "this is easy enough to verify with arbitrary instances (do you mean arbitrary $n$?)" — it seems that you have already had the proof. What is the question then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a basis for the vector space of symmetric matrices with an order of $n \times n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620757/find-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-symmetric-matrices-with-an-order-of-n-tim)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/898828/9464

Comment: So then is the main difficulty proving that, e.g. the number of entries in the upper half of an $n\times n$ matrix is $n(n+1)/2$?

Answer (score 1):

One way to formally prove that a vector space has a given dimension is to exhibit a basis and count the number of elements. In fact, the number of basis elements is one definition of dimension.

So, for instance, in the case of symmetric matrices, let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix which is all zeros except for the $i,j$ and $j,i$ entries, which are one. The set $S=\{ E_{ij}, i=1,...,n, i\leq j\}$ is a basis for the space, which can be shown by observing that an arbitrary symmetric matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ can be written as $\sum_{i\leq j} a_{ij} E_{ij}$ and that this is the unique decomposition of $A$ as a linear combination of the $E_{ij}$.